# Colocar datos de una Actividad en otra Actividad Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Ojala puedan ayudarme, Tengo una actividad que contiene:
(4 texview(cada texview tiene como dato el nombre de una persona)
Tambien tengo 4 botones , osea un textView para cada Boton.
quiero que Cada botón  me llame a Una Segunda  actividad(que contiene 1 texview).
y ¿ Lo que quiero es que cada vez que el botón llame a la segunda actividad me aparezca el dato que va en el texview? ....
Osea Si al dar click en el "botón 1" quiero que me aparezca la segunda actividad y el nombre que contiene el TEXVIEW 1 de la Primera Actividad, si le doy click al "BOTON 2" me aparece la segunda actividad pero con el dato del TEXVIEW 2 y así cada botón pueda mostrarme la misma actividad pero con el dato que le pertenece  a su TEXVIEW correspondiente . Ayuden porfa

Comment: Hola Diego, no has tenido ningun avance en tu codigo ? si es asi podrias mostrarlo para poder ver que tanto avance tienes.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los valores de otra clase, seria que declares la variable estatica y publica

```
public static String name;
private Button mandar;
```

En el onCreate

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
        mandar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tubotonenlayout);

        mandar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // tu acción
            }
       });
    }
```

ya en la otra clase simplemente puedes agregarla la variable estatica a un textview o lo que quieras

```
   TextView1.setText(name);
```

aqui te pedira que importes la clase pero esto lo puedes hacer presionando alt+enter